# Python Boto3 Firehose Client cannot connect to endpoint after a while

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a Python implemented service implemented on AWS ECS. Besides doing other things, it performs an AWS Firehose `put_record` for every operation. These "operations" are processed in parallel in multiple threads (many). Each thread eventually does the following:

```
try: 
    boto3.client("firehose").put_record(
                                DeliveryStreamName="my-delivery-stream",
                                Record={
                                    'Data': json.dumps(observation) + "\n"
                                }
except Exception as error:
    logging.error(error.args[0])
```

I get the following exception more often than not for the `put_record` call:

```
 'Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://firehose.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/'
```

What am I doing wrong?

What happens here is that the "retry" mechanism goes into full bore and, apparently, holds onto the file descriptor. More quickly than later, I get a resource exhaustion on everything else caused by "Too many open files." So, all new connections start failing, not just the ones to Firehose. This situation, of course, renders the entire service useless.

Any insight in to what may be a solution?

Firstly, I thought it was the `boto3` Firehose client, since I only had one for the entire process that was initialized on start up. So, I thought, maybe, this `boto3` thing was not thread safe. So, I switched to the approach above getting a new client for each `put_record`. That new client per operation approach was not any better than the single client per process approach.

Note, that it does work sometimes and some `put_record` calls do get through. So, it is NOT a firewall or AWS security group issue. Nor, is it an AWS credentials issue.

Is there some restriction or anomaly with Firehose or `boto3` of which I am unaware?

Comment: botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError most likely a region config issue. Is Firehose stream set up in `us-east-1` region?

Comment: The whole boto3 session should be set up for the region. Everything else in boto3 works, i.e. ec2, ecs, and s3.

Comment: Like I said above, some of the put_records do get through.

Comment: Also, it runs under an IAM Role on AWS, which has full access to ECS, EC2, S3 and Firehose and Athena. These services work and some put_record calls work. I am just wondering that if there is a throttling limit that I am unaware of, that AWS stops answering the phone so to speak. I am kind of miffed that if this is the case that the boto3 SDK does not take care of this kind of thing with a  thread safe buffering scheme.